# .NET reflector plugin for visual studio not working

Tags: visual-studio-2015, reflector, .net-reflector

I just downloaded .NET reflector plugin for VS (using 2015 RC) and it simply doesn't work. I'm not sure if I'm supposed to do anything but all the menu options are grayed out and the Microsoft.Owin assembly code you see in the background is not decompiled. The plugin version is 8.5.0.179 (latest).

What's the deal with this plugin, am I supposed to do something?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it turned out to be that my license didn't cover the installed version of .NET Reflector. I discovered the by trying to activate the tool. From the top menu select .NET Reflector->Help->Enter Serial Number. Enter the license number and hit Activate. Only then did it tell me my license wasn't valid. I had to login to red-gate and download the last version supported by my license.